# What galaxy or universe is the planet Ork in?

Tags: mork-and-mindy

In the 1978 science fiction television comedy *[Mork and Mindy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_&_Mindy)*, where is Mork's home planet Ork?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that Mork and Orson have realtime conversations, and Mork took Mindy to Ork, the distance can't be too terribly far. The lag is shown to be about 0.5-1 second, based upon the comedic beat timing of Williams and Winters.

Even if we assume a million times the speed of light, comm lag is 1 sec per 11.something light-days... roughly 1/135 the distance to Alpha C.

So if we presume that Ork can produce billion (1E9) times the speed of light comms, that's still only 319.4 LY radius - not even close to out of our spiral arm. At Trillion times light (1E12), it could be anywhere in the galaxy, or on one of the nearby dwarf galaxies orbiting/interpenetrating it.

So, given that travel isn't instant, and it takes about a day to fly to/from Ork and most systems of Sci-Fi FTL give under a 1 million to one advantage to communications speeds over ships (and many give a 1:1 ratio)... is probably within the same quarter of the galaxy, and I'd suspect about 100 light years away.

ISTR there being a mention of a billion times the speed of light in the series, but I've not seen it in 30 years.

Comment: A cigar for the using distance/comedic timing measurements to get to paragraph 4...

Comment: Damn, I miss cigars! (I quit smoking 4 years ago.)

Answer (score 3):

In the original *Happy Days* episode Mork wanted to take someone to Ork which he said would take about a *bleem*.  I think he said a *bleem* was about a thousand years so Fonzie fought him to save his friend.

Mork left for Ork at the end of the episodes, and returned to Earth a few decades later in *Mork and Mindy*, so a period of at least two *bleems* turned out to be only about two decades, and a *bleem*  should actually be less than a decade, possibly much less.  Mork does not seem to have been very good at math or translation.

In *Mork and Mindy*  the Orkan Elder seen in a couple of episodes was said to be about 70 years old if I remember, and once said that he hadn't experienced something for many *bleems*.

I think there was at least one quick trip to Ork and back, so either Mork used faster transportation than before or else a *bleem* would be only about a day or so.

And that is all I can remember about trip times to Ork.